# WCF security problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I have an app that accesses a WCF service on a server which is hosted in a console app. I don't have a problem there, it's when I try access another service from the console app that's on yet another server that i have the problem.

I'm using TCP to connect and i'm using all the default security values.

So i'm going from A->B and then it dies going from B->C with. Note that when i just go from A->C everything is fine

The error:
"a call to SSPI failed" ... "the target principal name is incorrect" ... stack trace ...

In B when i print out
Console.WriteLine(ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name);
Console.WriteLine("ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name);
i can see that it's my windows login which is fine

So it seems that it doesn't pass on my credentials when it goes from B->C

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

SSPI indicates you're using windows authentication.

Have you created a secure principal name for service C in your domain?  google the setspn command.  The issue is that windows will not pass a credential from the domain to an untrusted system.  You trust it by providing the secure principal name in the domain which then allows the token to be passed.

[Secure Principal Name SPN Creation Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949090.aspx)

Comment: As Spence mentions, this is cause because the credentials moves from A to B, but the same credential from B to C are not valid, because it is matched to the  AppDomain currently running that is different from B to C

Answer (score 3):

You are encountering what's called the Double Hop problem.
http://blogs.msdn.com/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx.
The solution is generally to use Kerberos authentication, which as Spence says, involves things like SPNs.

Comment: This is *precisely* what I am encountering.  I will dig into this with a full cup of coffee and wait for the lightbulb moment.  Thanks!